# Camel CDI runtime InstanceAlreadyExistsException on JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, cdi

When multiple wars are deployed, and each war file contains one instance of a class StandardContext that extends DefaultCamelContext and context name is set to "StandardContext" using @ContextName, this exception gets thrown. Is this due to class loader setup on JBoss?
Camel version: 2.17.4
JBoss version: EAP 6.1

Comment: How do you deploy your Camel application. Do you use a WAR or do you use wildfly-camel or something? And a good idea is to use unique camel id names, so eg @ContextName should use unique name in all your applications

Comment: The camel application is deployed as a war file on JBoss EAP 6.1. Unfortunately the ContextName cannot be changed, as it is a common base class used by every war file, but the workaround is to use the module name as the name pattern:

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I had used

```
    getManagementNameStrategy().setNamePattern("#name#");
```

But that did not work, so I modified my code to the following:

```
    @ApplicationScoped
    @ContextName("StandardContext")
    public class StandardContext extends DefaultCamelContext {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:module/ModuleName")
    private String moduleName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    getManagementNameStrategy().setNamePattern(moduleName);
```

Posting this code to clarify my solution for other readers

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Camel application to use a naming pattern (such as managementNamePattern) for JMX. See more details in the JMX documentation: http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html

You can then let the pattern use a counter or something to avoid the clash. Or you can override the name and set it to something you know is unique such as the module name.